# Receive Sms and forward it by email

Tags: sms, gsm, at-command

We have a customer where we have a remote access to our server. It is secured by user/pwd and a passcode that is currently send by e-mail to an e-mail acount of our company where all our support staff has access to.

Due to a new company rule of our customer the current e-mail solution is no longer allowed. They force us to provide a mobile number where they can send a sms to that contains the passcode.

As we have multiple locations where our support members are located we have now the problem that if the customer calls, the passcode is no longer directly accessible. Especially during the night there is only one support member on service and he has to call one of the other members to pass him the passcode.

My idea was to read the sms from an old mobile and to forward the sms on receival by mail or to make it accessible by an application on one of our service pc's.

I've managed to establish a rs232 connection to some mobiles and to send sms with them. The problem is, that the at command interface of all mobiles I have fir testing is restricted to not being able to read sms frim the mobiles memory.

Now my question: 
Do you know of any (industrial) gsm module where I can read sms from? 
Do you habe any recommondation.

I habe found a Siemens device myself on google but it costs ~400€ and I don't have the possibility to spend that money withiut knowing that it will work :-/

Edit: As a side information: I'm not allowed to use any internet service.

Thank you for any input.

Comment: That's a hard one, but if you want something simple and CHEAP, you could try to make an Android app that communicates with your server via rest services, then you just send the messages to that endpoint

Comment: is it possible to access the sms with an app? Or do I need a rooted mobile for it?

Comment: You can, matter of setting the according permissions: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html search for "sms"